# ListBox index changed shows wrong value from SQLite database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, listbox

I am coding a VB.NET program, which uses SQLite as a database.

My problem is when the form is loading it is displaying all values from a particular column (questions in my case) from the database to the `ListBox`. Then if the user clicks on any item (`ListBox` index change), the corresponding value from the database (answer) displays in a `RichTextBox`. This works as expected.

When the user types something in a `TextBox` and clicks the search `Button`, it is expected to show the questions from the database according to `TextBox.Text` as a tag column in the database to the same `ListBox`. This also works fine.

The problem begins when the `ListBox` index changes now. If the search result is only one item in the `ListBox`, the index will be zero and the `RichTextBox` shows the first item of the database insted of the corresponding value of the `ListBox` item.

My code is here:

```
Sub showData()'''this shows questions when form loads
    connect()
    Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from elect", connection)
    'Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "elect")
    Dim mySelectQuery As String = "select * from elect"
    Dim sqConnection As New SQLiteConnection(connection)
    Dim sqCommand As New SQLiteCommand(mySelectQuery, sqConnection)
    'sqConnection.Open()
    Try
        Dim sqReader As SQLiteDataReader = sqCommand.ExecuteReader()


        ' Always call Read before accessing data.
        Do While sqReader.Read()
            Dim sName = sqReader.Item("question")

            ListBox1.Items.Add(sName)
        Loop

        ' always call Close when done reading.
        sqReader.Close()

        ' Close the connection when done with it.
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try


End Sub


Public Sub NavigateRecords()
    page1.Clear()''page is rich text box


    connect()
    Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from elect", connection)
    'Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "elect")

    Dim mySelectQuery As String

    mySelectQuery = "select * from elect"

    Dim sqConnection As New SQLiteConnection(connection)
    Dim sqCommand As New SQLiteCommand(mySelectQuery, sqConnection)
    Dim num As Integer = Me.inc = Conversions.ToInteger(ListBox1.SelectedIndices.ToString)
    MsgBox(num)
    Me.inc = Conversions.ToInteger(ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString)
    If (Me.inc > -1) Then

            Dim ans As String = Conversions.ToString(ds.Tables.Item("elect").Rows.Item(Me.inc).Item(2))

            page1.Text = (ans)
End If
End Sub

Private Sub search()
    connect()
    Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from elect", connection)
    'Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "elect")
    Dim mySelectQuery As String = ("select * from elect WHERE tag like'%" & txtSearch.Text & "%' ")
    Dim sqConnection As New SQLiteConnection(connection)
    Dim sqCommand As New SQLiteCommand(mySelectQuery, sqConnection)
    Try
        Dim sqReader As SQLiteDataReader = sqCommand.ExecuteReader()

        ' Always call Read before accessing data.
        Do While sqReader.Read()
            Dim sName = sqReader.Item("question")

            ListBox1.Items.Add(sName)
        Loop
        If ListBox1.Items.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Nothing Found ")

            showData()





        End If
        ' always call Close when done reading.
        sqReader.Close()

        ' Close the connection when done with it.
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    page1.Visible = True

    ListBox1.Visible = False

    Label1.Visible = False

        NavigateRecords()

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you try to make the paragraph cleaner and more comprehensible is a bit hard to follow. If i understood well all you have to do is add a primary key in your database for every item and then just use the primary key to get the record

Comment: No need to hit the DB over and over and over.  Load the data to a datatable (or two depending on the structure)

Comment: Thanks plutonix, that can be done. pls guide me to achieve my goal. I think I have to relate listbox with database, but as new to both .net and database i am not succeeding to find a solution- even though searched for .